# Using a yacc file to detect syntax errors in a text area in Java

Tags: java, parsing, yacc

I have a yacc file that was created by someone else quite a long time ago. The file describes a custom language. My goal is to use that yacc file to create a parser for my custom text area in my Java application. The endgoal is to show errors when the syntax is incorrect.
I'm currently using RSyntaxTextArea which handles highlighting rather nicely (based on my own implementation, not the yacc file), but creating a parser that can detect every possible error the user can make is a much harder task.

The way I see it I have three options:

1. The best case scenario would be if somehow I could use the yacc file I have directly in my Java application.
2. The second best case would be if there'd be a way to parse the yacc file to a format I can easily use in Java. I found BYACC/J which creates a Java class from the yacc file, but the file I got was riddled with syntax errors (missing functions, variables, etc.), so that didn't work out too well.
3. As I see it the third option would be to learn YACC and another parser generator that I can use in Java and rewrite the whole thing in that. Learning new things is never a bad thing, but since my time is not endless and these "compiler compilers" seem to have a rather steep learning curve, I'd only want to invest time in it, if there's no way to use the YACC definition directly.
   As I've found there are quite a lot of potential options out there, between JavaCC, Jacc, CUP, ANTLR4 and probably lots of others, I'd want to choose one that's as close to yacc as possible to reduce the implementation time.
   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bison (the "yacc-compatible" parser generator most commonly mistakenly called "yacc") [can generate Java parsers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Java-Parsers). Having said that, I've never tried it so I have no idea what problems you would run into.

A "yacc" grammar includes semantic rules in the target language; if you have an existing grammar, the semantic rules will probably be written in C. Yacc grammars also depend on the existence of a scanner, often created with `flex` (or `JFlex` for Java, which works in a very similar manner).

In order to use a Java-based solution, even one which uses the same grammar syntax, you would need to rewrite all of the semantic actions in your existing yacc grammar as well as rewrite the accompanying scanner. That would also be the case for BYacc/J; you cannot just provide a C-targetted yacc grammar file to a parser generator and expect to get a functioning Java parser.

So you would definitely need to learn how yacc/bison/flex work.

Note: Bison (and friends) are designed to parse syntactically-correct programs. Obviously they can detect a syntax error, but recovering from the syntax error to continue the parse is a lot trickier; for syntax highlighting, you definitely want to be able to detect more than one error if at all possible. So you may well find that your existing yacc grammar is only a start.